Android can not start Service with ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException
I have a Service called ServiceTechnicianTrackingService that tracks location with foreground notification of the people using phone.
public class ServiceTechnicianTrackingService extends Service {

private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
private LocationCallback locationCallback;

@Inject ServiceTechnicianLocationManager serviceTechnicianCoordinateManager;
@Inject NetworkManager networkManager;

public static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "action_stop_service";
private boolean isStarted = false;

@Nullable @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
return null;
}

@Override public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
injector().inject(this);

fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
  @Override public void onLocationResult(@NotNull LocationResult locationResult) {
    if(locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
      super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
      String lat = String.valueOf(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude());
      String lng = String.valueOf(locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude());

      Timber.d("Lat is: " + lat + " lng is: " + lng);
      if(networkManager.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        serviceTechnicianCoordinateManager.updateCurrentLocation(new Coordinate(lat, lng));
      }
    }
  }
};
}

 @Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// Call startForeground early to prevent the exception
if(!isStarted) {
  startForegroundAndDisplayNotification();
  isStarted = true;
}

if(intent != null) {
  String action = intent.getAction();
  if(ACTION_STOP_SERVICE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
  } else {
    requestLocationUpdates();
  }
}
return START_STICKY;
}

@Override public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
stopLocationUpdates();
isStarted = false;
}

private void startForegroundAndDisplayNotification() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
  Notification notification = createNotification();
  startForeground(1, notification);
 }
}

private Notification createNotification() {
// code to create notification
}
}

And this service is called from MainActivity like this:
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    injector().inject(this);
    presenter.setView(this);


    trackServiceTechnicianIfNeeded();
  }

  private void trackServiceTechnicianIfNeeded() {
    if (presenter.isTrackable()) {
      if (ViewUtil.isPlayServiceAvailable(this)) {
        if (isForegroundLocationPermissionGranted() && presenter.isTrackTechnicianRouteAllowed()) {
          tryToStartForegroundLocationService();
          presenter.saveThatUserAskedForPermission();
        } else {
          if (!presenter.isUserAskedForLocationPermission()) {
            askForLocationPermission();
            presenter.saveThatUserAskedForPermission();
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      stopServiceTechnicianLocationService();
    }
  }

  private void tryToStartForegroundLocationService() {
    if(Utils.isPlayServiceAvailable(this)) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if(isPostNotificationsPermissionGranted()) {
          startForegroundService();
        } else {
          askForPostNotificationsPermission();
        }
      } else {
        startForegroundService();
      }
    }
  }

  private void startForegroundService() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ServiceTechnicianTrackingService.class);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      startForegroundService(i);
    } else {
      startService(i);
    }
  }

  @Override public void stopServiceTechnicianLocationService() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, ServiceTechnicianTrackingService.class));
  }

but I get this exception:
      Caused by android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.anstar.fieldworkhq/.coordinates.ServiceTechnicianTrackingService
   at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)
   at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel(ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:50)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal(Parcel.java:4882)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:4864)
   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3064)
   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:7234)
   at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:775)
   at com.anstar.fieldworkhq.coordinates.ServiceTechnicianTrackingService.startForegroundAndDisplayNotification(ServiceTechnicianTrackingService.java:97)
   at com.anstar.fieldworkhq.coordinates.ServiceTechnicianTrackingService.onStartCommand(ServiceTechnicianTrackingService.java:72)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:5268)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs()
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2531)

